# How to map from same source node to different destination elements based on qualifiers using BizTalk functoids

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I need to map:

- when C51601 =64 map C51602 to FreightCost
- when C51601 = 9 map C51602 to InvoiceTotalAmount.

But only FreightCost or InvoiceTotalAmount is getting mapped. I want both 
FreightCost and InvoiceTotalAmount to to be displayed in the output by only using normal BizTalk functoids not XSLT.

Can we achieve this only using functoids?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried connecting two looping functoids to the C516_12 node and one of these going to FreightCost and the other to InvoiceTotalAmount?

Comment: There are complex maps that cannot be done without using XSL. I agree with @Dijkgraaf that looping functoids may work. You can also right click on the map and select 'Validate map'. The output window will show the generated XSL. You can open that file and verify how biztalk translated your map into XSL

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, all you need to do is connect C516_12 to FreightCost (etc) through a Looping Functoid.

Meaning **C516_12 -> Looping Functoid -> FreightCost**

Comment: C516_12 -> Looping Functoid -> FreightCost this approach is working . Thanks a lot for your inputs .

Comment: @Manu For the benefit of others, please mark the appropriate Answer.